# Flutter: ListView height is getting reduced when other widgets are available

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I am developing a flutter application and there, I am dynamically generating a list of `checkboxes`. so to do this, I used `ListView.Builder`.

Below is my full code, you can implement it at your end easily.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddAccountPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Services"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              "Save",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints:
            BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
        child: Container(
          child: _AddAccountUI(),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class _AddAccountUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _AddAccountState();
  }
}

class _AddAccountState extends State<_AddAccountUI> {
  List<int> checkBoxElements = [];
  List<String> checkBoxStrings =['one','two','three','four'];

  bool _onTheSpotServices=false;
  bool _homeVisits=false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Text(
            "Let's add your company into the system. Just fill out the form below.",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
          ),
        ),
        _imageSelector(),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Text(
            "Company Name",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 15),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 36,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter some text';
                }
                return null;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                contentPadding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom: 2, left: 8),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20),
          child: Text(
            "Business Type",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 20),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 36,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              hint: Text(
                "Please Select",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              ),
              items:
                  <String>['Foo000000000', 'Bar00000000'].map((String value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(
                    value,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (_) {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20, bottom: 10),
          child: Text(
            "Category",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
          ),
        ),

        Expanded(
          child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 4,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return _TickBox(checkBoxElements, index);
                  })),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20, bottom: 20),
          child: Text(
            "Location",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 15),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 36,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter some text';
                }
                return null;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                contentPadding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom: 2, left: 8),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(child: _switchMaker(),),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _imageSelector() {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(212, 208, 208, 100),
            ),
            color: Color.fromRGBO(242, 242, 242, 100),
          ),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
          child: Center(child: Text("Add Your Cover Photo")),
        ));
  }

  Widget _switchMaker() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left:20),
                          child: Text(
                "Provide on the spot services",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(flex: 1,),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:20, right: 20),
                          child: Text(
                "Make Home Visits",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Row(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 20),
            child: Switch(value: _onTheSpotServices, onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                _onTheSpotServices=value;
              });
            }, )),
          Spacer(flex: 1,),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:10, right:20),
            child: Switch(value: _homeVisits, onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                _homeVisits=value;
              });
            }, )),
        ],)
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _TickBox extends StatefulWidget {
  List<int> checkBoxElements = [];
  int dataValue = 0;

  _TickBox(List<int> elements, int value) {
    checkBoxElements = elements;
    dataValue = value;
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _TickBoxState();
  }
}

class _TickBoxState extends State<_TickBox> {
  bool value = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
      child: CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text(
          "Garage shop with general repair",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
        ),
        onChanged: (bool val) {
          setState(() {
            value = val;

            if (widget.checkBoxElements.contains(widget.dataValue)) {
              widget.checkBoxElements.remove(widget.dataValue);
            } else {
              widget.checkBoxElements.add(widget.dataValue);
            }

            print(widget.checkBoxElements);
          });
        },
        value: value,
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now the issue is, the items generated by the `ListView.Builder` are totally compacted, only one item is visible. To see the rest, you have to scroll.

I tried using  `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` and `shrinkWrap:false` to stop the scroll. It did work, however the items are still compacted.

tHIS IS how it looks like. To check the checkboxes, look under **Category**

[image]

I NEED these items to be displayed in full, without scrolling.How can I do that?

Comment: This happens when you have two scrollable items. You you can fix it by setting the size of your second list when building a layout or programmatically if the size of the items changes. Or find a different way to design your layout where you don't need two scrollable items.

Comment: @maja89 I do not need 2 scrolling items. I only need the full view to scroll, not the checkboxes. If there is another way in flutter to build the checkboxes in a loop instead of a 'ListView'0i am happy to use .

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the `Expanded` widget and add the following properties in `ListView.builder`:

```
      Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 4,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _TickBox(checkBoxElements, index);
        }),
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried. Then it sorted the issue but ended up with `overflow` issue, where it displays the yellow stripe

Answer (score 0):

Use 'SingleChildScrollView'. That should get you going!